# 'FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it' when using OwnsOne()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have several Stored Procedures which I use to search the database. Each returns several fields to do with the amount of data found/returned. The models look like this:

```csharp
// simplified
public abstract class SearchResult {
  public int RowCount { get; set; }
  public int FilteredRowCount { get; set; }
  // other properties
}

public class FooSearch {
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Foo { get; set; }
  public SearchResult Result { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the DBContext I'm using `OwnsOne()` to link the classes, as per [this MS guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#explicit-configuration)

```
public DbSet<FooSearch> FooSearch { get; set; }

// OnModelCreating
builder.Entity<FooSearch>().OwnsOne(t => t.Result);
```

Finally I make the SP call:

```
var searchResult = db.FooSearch.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE [Search].[Foo] {0}, {1}", foo, bar).ToList();
```

However this last step is giving me the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling `AsEnumerable` after the FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated method to perform the composition on the client side.'

Changing `ToList()` to `AsEnumerable()` makes no difference to the result.

If I remove the `OwnsOne()` and the `Result` property from the `FooSearch` class then the SP works and I get results. What is the cause of this issue, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I face same problem... Do u have solution?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem as well.

Comment: I had this issue and it was solved using the `AsEnumerable()` method as suggested by the exception message I got.
The problem in my case was I was trying to retrieve a composed entity (i.e. a property is typed after another entity). It could not retrieve the data. `AsEnumerable()` was told to do the composition job and it worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I faced the same issue and fixed it after reading the issue [#18232](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18232).

You need to add `.IgnoreQueryFilters()` after `FromSqlRaw`. Like that:

```cs
var searchResult = db.FooSearch
.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE [Search].[Foo] {0}, {1}", foo, bar)
.IgnoreQueryFilters()
.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! My entity has a query filter and this fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

First Of all, you need to inform the model builder that your entity is a Keyless
entity

1. `modelBuilder.Entity<FooSearch>().HasNoKey().ToView(null)`
2. when using a keyless entity or executing RawSQL, EF will map all of the
   properties mentioned in the query to your "FooSearch", how would ef map to
   `SearchResult` object?
3. remove the `SearchResult` and replace it with fields you need to select.